# Erlang - Data not received when issuing ssl:send(Socket, Data)

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, erlang, client-server

I'm using Erlang with SSL, 
My server socket listens to incoming client connections and spawns a new thread for every incoming connection (assume the looping function called `clientroutine()`)

This thread is designed based on this tutorial I found on web: http://erlycoder.com/89/erlang-ssl-sockets-example-ssl-echo-server-ssl-client-

so basically `clientroutine()` waits in `receive`, gets data from client, does some action based on received data and recursively calls itself again

Now, the problem is that when I issue `ssl:send(Socket, Data)`, the client (Java-based) does not get anything from inputstream

Interestingly, this happens only when I recursively call `clientroutine()` after `ssl:send` like this (I skip socket close and default cases for simplicity):

```
clientroutine(Socket) ->

 ssl:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),

 receive   

 {ssl, Sock , Data} ->
           ok = ssl:send(Sock, "~100 bytes list goes to client"),    
           clientroutine(Socket)  
 end.
```

The following works correctly (i.e. no recursion takes places and thread finishes) and my Java-client receives the string from inputstream:

```
clientroutine(Socket) ->

 ssl:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),

 receive   

 {ssl, Sock , Data} ->
           ok = ssl:send(Sock, "~100 bytes list goes to client")                
 end.
```

Java-client launches inputstream listener in a separate thread like this (`BufferedReader in` has been declared above, among class fields):

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            String msg;

            try {
                while((msg=in.readLine())!=null)

                    System.out.println("user received: " + msg);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("user: exception occured - inputstream reader");             
            }

        }}).start();
```

I haven't yet checked if this works with Erlang client or not, I will update my post when I check it as well, but anyhow I need it to work with Java client

Any ideas why this happens? 
Probably I should use some other BufferedReader routine instead of `readLine()`, or maybe BufferedReader requires some special character to be pushed into outputstream after the transferred message?

UPDATE. Erlang client receives everything correctly, with and without recursive call. Seems that this is somewhat related to Java inputstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the newline character required for `readLine()` to fetch a line from inputstream, was (strangely) not included when I was sending my message in "recursive" version of the program, so everything goes well after I append `\n` to the transferred message